# Unable to finish TLS handshake for my express webserver

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https

Here's my webserver, most parts not included in favor of being concise.

`server.js`

```js
 const https = require('https');
 const app = require('express')();
 
 const port = 1000;

 const options = {
    key : getKey(),
    cert: getCert(),
    ciphers: getCiphers(),
    passphrase: "abcd",
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    requestCert: true
  };

 const server = https.createServer(options, app);
 server.on('clientError', function (err) {
     console.log('received client error');
     console.log({err});
 })
 server.on('connection', function (err) {
     console.log('client connected'); 
 })
 server.listen(port);
```

To test my server, I run a connection commands with `openssl`

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:1000 \
                 -servername localhost \
                 -CAfile etc/root-cert/ca.cert.pem \
                 -cert etc/certs/client.cert.pem \
                 -key etc/private/client.key.pem
```

This returns the following output, which indicates that the TLS connection was successful (as far as I'm aware):

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, ST = California, O = Hackysack, CN = Hackysack Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = California, O = Hackysack, CN = Hackysack Intermediate CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, O = Hackysack, CN = localhost
verify return:1
write W BLOCK
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/O=Hackysack/CN=localhost
   i:/C=US/ST=California/O=Hackysack/CN=Hackysack Intermediate CA
 1 s:/C=US/ST=California/O=Hackysack/CN=Hackysack Intermediate CA
   i:/C=US/ST=California/O=Hackysack/CN=Hackysack Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[Long cert file here]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/O=Hackysack/CN=localhost
issuer=/C=US/ST=California/O=Hackysack/CN=Hackysack Intermediate CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3400 bytes and written 2061 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AEAD-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : AEAD-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1674855496
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read:errno=0
```

However, in my server terminal logs I see that I receive a `clientError` when trying to make this call via HTTPS request.

```
{
  err: Error: socket hang up
      at connResetException (internal/errors.js:639:14)
      at TLSSocket.onSocketClose (_tls_wrap.js:1063:23)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:412:35)
      at net.js:686:12
      at Socket.done (_tls_wrap.js:564:7)
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
      at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:686:12) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
  }
}
```

Here's my client request:

```js
 const https = require('https');
 
 const options = {
     hostname: 'localhost',
     port: 1000,
     method: "POST",
     path: "/test",
     cert: getClientCert(),
     key:  getClientKey(),
     passphrase: "abcd",
     ciphers: getCiphers()
     ca: getCA(),
      
 }
 const request = https.request(options);
```

I noticed this error only started happening when I included `requestCert: true` when I created the server. I think something must be going wrong with my client side for this to be the case. The main problem with debugging this is that I'm not receiving a good error when it fails the handshake.

How can I better debug this issue?

Comment: Evidently you also need to include the `ca` option in your server options to get client auth.

Comment: Unfortunately even after including the `ca` I am still receiving the same error